# How does movb set the filename extension to .asm?

Tags: assembly

I was looking [at dos version 1.25 source code and I came across a file name ASM](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/80ab2fddfdf30f09f0a0a637654cbb3cd5c7baa6/v1.25/source/ASM.ASM). I think that this is the part of the lexer.

I came across the `MOVB` instruction and in the notes it says that this sets the filename extension to "asm":

```
MOV [LSTFCB],AL
MOV [LSTDEV],AH ;Flag device for list ouput
MOV SI,EXTEND
MOV DI,FCB+9
MOVW
MOVB            ;Set extension to ASM
MOVW            ;Zero extent field
```

How does this work?

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about DOS internals, or assembly programming, but the `+9` seems relevant, since DOS FAT filenames have the famous 8.3 format, and thus the extension starts at character (and in DOS FAT character == byte) number 9.

Comment: It is initializing a [file control block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Control_Block).  The filename extension is at offset 9, "ASM" takes 3 bytes.  So MOVW + MOVB in 16-bit code.

Answer (score 3):

The label `EXTEND`, which address is moved to the source index (`SI`) register, [points to the string `'ASM',0,0`](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/80ab2fddfdf30f09f0a0a637654cbb3cd5c7baa6/v1.25/source/ASM.ASM#L3943) (note the two zero bytes at the end). The destination index (`DI`) register points to the [file control block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Control_Block) at offset 9, which corresponds to the file extension in the [DOS 8.3 file name format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename).

The following `movw` and `movb` instructions then copy 2+1+2 bytes from `EXTEND` to `FCB`, while simultaneously incrementing `SI` and `DI` ([instruction reference](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq)).

Comment: The reference you linked is for movs, not movb or movw. Is there some assembler that accepts movb and movw for movsb and movsw, or is that an error in the question?

Comment: I don't think that this is an error, since the code is from 1982 and was copied from the official MS-DOS source repo. Personally I don't recall any assembler using this syntax; probably it was some internal tool that has been discontinued/updated since then.

Comment: It appears that the assembler that supports MOVB/MOVW as an alias for MOVSB/MOVSW is the very one that the example code in the question is taken from.